# mySQL not give NULL as value to empty field

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

in my mysql if I leave title input empty and save data to table some time it's leave field empty but don't give NULL as value, I set the default value as NULL but still leave field empty instead of write NULL. I don't know why; I want to give field NULL if the title or text input are empty when it's inserting data
in the images I show that the table is set to give NULL if field is empty in the second image show that some time give NULL some time don't. because in my php I set if value is NULL show `<p>No title</p>` but in this case I'm getting empty `<p><p>`
[image]

[image]

--Insert Code (is Yii2 Framework)

```
public static function CreatePost ($MPEMBED)
    {
        $info = Embed::create( $MPEMBED->post_url );

        $urlImage = $info->image;

        $MPEMBED->post_urlTitle = $info->title;
        $MPEMBED->post_urlProvider = $info->providerIcon;
        $MPEMBED->post_urlCode = $info->code;
        $MPEMBED->post_urlPreview = $urlImage;
        $MPEMBED->filestype_id = 100;
        $mediaName = AxValuePost::FileName();
        $mediaFolder = $MPEMBED->post_mediafolder;

        if ($info !== NULL){
            mkdir($mediaFolder, 0777, true);

            $data = file_get_contents($urlImage);
            $new = $mediaFolder . $mediaName .rand().'png';
            $MEDIA = file_put_contents($new, $data);

            if ($MEDIA !== NULL)
            {
                // To upload to DB (TO PASS A DATA TO VALUE TO MYSQL EXP )
                $MPEMBED->post_media = $new;
            }   
        }
        $MPEMBED->save()
    }
```

-- Output Code

```
public static function PostLink($post, $cssClass)
    {
        if ($post->post_title == NULL ){
            return Html::a(Yii::t('app', $post->post_urlTitle), ['/content/post', 'chn' => $post->channel->channel_title, 'pst' => $post->post_uid], ['class'=> $cssClass ]);
        }else{
            return Html::a(Yii::t('app', $post->post_title), ['/content/post', 'chn' => $post->channel->channel_title, 'pst' => $post->post_uid], ['class'=> $cssClass ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full source code where you inserts a new row into the database and the full source code where you output the content of the MySQL table.

Comment: So, can `$info->title` be an empty string?

Comment: my var_dump show 'C:\wamp\www\yii2ctab\frontend\views\files\widget\embed-view-urllink.php:11:string '' isn't empty mean NULL ?

Comment: Protip: `''` is not `NULL`, it is an empty string. It will be stored and retrieved as such.

Comment: solved by condition if empty(); Thank you.

Comment: @Sammitch why not post that as an answer

Comment: I posted that in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using empty(); `if ($post->post_title == NULL )`

to

`if ($post->post_title == NULL || empty($post->post_title))`

changed :

```
public static function PostLink($post, $cssClass)
    {
        if ($post->post_title == NULL ){
            return Html::a(Yii::t('app', $post->post_urlTitle), ['/content/post', 'chn' => $post->channel->channel_title, 'pst' => $post->post_uid], ['class'=> $cssClass ]);
        }else{
            return Html::a(Yii::t('app', $post->post_title), ['/content/post', 'chn' => $post->channel->channel_title, 'pst' => $post->post_uid], ['class'=> $cssClass ]);
        }
    }
```

to :

```
public static function PostLink($post, $cssClass)
        {
            if ($post->post_title == NULL || empty($post->post_title)){
                return Html::a(Yii::t('app', $post->post_urlTitle), ['/content/post', 'chn' => $post->channel->channel_title, 'pst' => $post->post_uid], ['class'=> $cssClass ]);
            }else{
                return Html::a(Yii::t('app', $post->post_title), ['/content/post', 'chn' => $post->channel->channel_title, 'pst' => $post->post_uid], ['class'=> $cssClass ]);
            }
        }
```